# Snapcraft Python2 building numpy with python-dev

Tags: python, snap, numpy

just starting to get my hands dirty with snappy. I am trying to port a python project to a snappy app. The python code relies on numpy 1.5.1, which relies on python-dev being installed.

My snapcraft parts section looks like:

```
parts:
    mypythonapp:
        plugin: python2
        source: https://github.com/me/mypythonapp.git
        source-type: git
        build-packages:
            - gcc
            - gfortran
            - libblas-dev
            - liblapack-dev
            - cython
            - python-dev
        python-packages:
            - numpy==1.5.1
```

When I `snapcraft pull` it attempts to build numpy, but errors out with:

```
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
        In file included from numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c.src:7:0:
        numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_common.h:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
        compilation terminated.
        In file included from numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c.src:7:0:
        numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_common.h:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
        compilation terminated.

error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -I/home/me/Code/mypythonapp-snap/parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include -I/home/me/Code/mypythonapp-snap/parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include -I/home/me/Code/mypythonapp-snap/parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/home/me/Code/mypythonapp-snap/parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include -I/home/me/Code/mypythonapp-snap/parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include -I/home/me/Code/mypythonapp-snap/parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -fPIC -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/umath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.o"
```

I can find `Python.h` located at `./parts/mypythonapp/install/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`. When I look at the all the included paths I notice that `usr/include/python2.7` is not there.

Is there anyway for me to include a path similar to the autotools plugin configflags? Or am I missing something easy?

**edit**:
I have made some progress by modifying `env` function in the python2 plugin located at  `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snapcraft/plugins/python2.py`

The original function looked like:

```
  def env(self, root):
    # This is until we figure out how to get pip to download only
    # and then build in the build step or split out pulling
    # stage-packages in an internal private step.
    env = [
        'CPPFLAGS="-I{} $CPPFLAGS"'.format(os.path.join(
            root, 'usr', 'include')),
        'CFLAGS="-I{} $CFLAGS"'.format(os.path.join(
            root, 'usr', 'include')),
    ]
```

I modified it to look like:

```
def env(self, root):
    # This is until we figure out how to get pip to download only
    # and then build in the build step or split out pulling
    # stage-packages in an internal private step.
    env = [
        'CPPFLAGS="-I{} $CPPFLAGS"'.format(os.path.join(
            root, 'usr', 'include')),
        'CFLAGS="-I{} $CFLAGS"'.format(os.path.join(
            root, 'usr', 'include')),
        'CPPFLAGS="-I{} $CPPFLAGS"'.format(os.path.join(
            root, 'usr', 'include', 'python2.7')),
        'CFLAGS="-I{} $CFLAGS"'.format(os.path.join(
            root, 'usr', 'include' 'python2.7')),
    ]
```

Now it picks up the `Python.h`, but it fails to find `scalartypes.c`

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule_onefile.c
    numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule_onefile.c:10:25: fatal error: scalartypes.c: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule_onefile.c:10:25: fatal error: scalartypes.c: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Can you maybe give a link to a repository or pastebin of the entire code somewhere? That might make it easier to help out.

Answer (score 0):

What you doing seems wrong, these make conflict:

- `plugin: python2` which expects a `setup.py`
- `python-packages: - numpy==1.5.1` included `numpy` python package as dependency, why you said building it.
- `build-packages:  - gcc  - gfortran  - libblas-dev  - liblapack-dev  - cython  - python-dev` added all this C/CPP tools and libraries like going to compile may be a `make`, `autotools`, .. project

The question is missing the original code or a link to it to review and reproducing. However, I would recommend:

- Split the `Parts:` and set the `plugin` needed for each by checking source/doc.
- Order the build process using: `after`
- Is it really needed to build a dependency specific version or pre-built package from repository is enough? See `stage-snaps` & `stage-packages`.